# IDLEで改行すると>>>というマークが消えてしまう

Tags: python, python-idle

pythonのIDLEを使用しています。改行すると `>>>` というマークが消えてしまいコードが上手くうてないので解決方法が分かる方いましたら教えてください！

```
x = 100

if x == 10:
    print("10!)
elif x == 20:
    print("20!)
else:
    print("分かりません")
```

Comment: ダブルクォーテーションが閉じていないだけでは・・・

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確認したのですがIDLEの方ではあダブルクォーテーション閉じてました

Comment: 何か他の開発環境オススメなものはありますか？MAC仕様です

Comment: 現状のIDLEの内容に合わせて質問文のコードを編集していただけますか？開発環境については別の質問になるため、質問を分けてください（おすすめを求める形の質問はスタックオーバーフローでは好まれませんが）。